# Function that returns a list of unevaluated functions in mathematica

Tags: functional-style

I have a list of that contains words of two non commutative variables. Something like :

```
{x, y, inv[x], inv[y], x ** y, 1, x ** inv[y], x ** x, y ** inv[x], 
 y ** x, y ** y, inv[x] ** inv[y], inv[x] ** y, inv[x] ** inv[x], 
 inv[y] ** x, inv[y] ** inv[x], inv[y] ** inv[y]}
```

I would like to take this list as an input to a function a return a list of unevaluated functions of the two variables. In other words the output should be something like :

```
{R1[x_,y_]:=x,R2[x_,y_]:=y,R3[x_,y_]:=inv[y],R4[x_,y_]=x ** y,...}
```

I am sure I am not using the right script here but I want to convey the idea that I want to return a sequence of functions that I am going to evaluate later in another function.

Comment: You mean you want a list of function *definitions*, each wrapped in `Hold`, to avoid evaluation? Or you want to automatically define these functions?

Comment: The definition is given in the list entered (an example is the first list above). So, I guess this fits in the first part of your question.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Can you give an example of the actual output you want?  `R1[x_,y_]:=x` cannot be the output because it immediately evaluates. `Hold[R1[x_,y_]:=x]` can be. Or do you just want to write a program that *evaluates* `R1[x_,y_]:=x` (not *outputs it as a result*)?

Comment: I am sorry. Here is an example : R1[x+y,z]=x+y. Another example R2[x*y,a]=x*y. I do not want the function to return the evaluation. I want it to return the function itself (in the simple case). In the more complicated case, I would like to return a list of such functions. Each one of them is also unevaluated.

Comment: `R1[x_,y_]:=x` is not a function.  It is a function definition. The function itself is `R1`.  The definition cannot be returned unevaluated unless you wrap it by `Hold`.  The function name can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by defining a helper function which will assemble the individual function definitions:

```
makeAssignment[wrapper_][e_, {i_}] :=
  (  ToExpression["R"~~ToString[i], InputForm, Hold]
  /. Hold[s_] :> Hold[s[x_, y_], e]
  /. Hold[l_, r_] :> wrapper[SetDelayed[l, r]]
  )
```

Since we wish to prevent the definitions from evaluating immediately, we must wrap the expression in something that will prevent such evaluation.  `makeAssignment` is defined in a way that allows us to try out different wrappers.

For example, we can simply `Hold` the result:

```
makeAssignment[Hold][x**y, {5}]

(* Hold[R5[x_, y_] := x ** y] *)
```

Or, we can use `Defer` to prevent the evaluation but generate a final top-level output that uses no wrapper:

```
makeAssignment[Defer][x**y, {5}]

(* R5[x_, y_] := x ** y *)
```

Or, we can use `HoldForm` which will give a result that *looks* like it has no wrapper but in fact has an invisible one:

```
makeAssignment[HoldForm][x**y, {5}]

(* R5[x_, y_] := x ** y *)

Head[%]

(* HoldForm *)
```

We can even use `Identity` if we do not want to hold the evaluation at all and actually install the definition:

```
makeAssignment[Identity][x**y, {5}]

(* Null *)

??R5

(* R5[x_,y_] := x**y *)
```

We can now use this helper function to produce a desired list using various strategies of evaluation control.

Given:

```
$vs = { x, y, inv[x], inv[y], x ** y, 1, x ** inv[y], x ** x
      , y ** inv[x], y ** x, y ** y, inv[x] ** inv[y], inv[x] ** y
      , inv[x] ** inv[x], inv[y] ** x, inv[y] ** inv[x], inv[y] ** inv[y]
      };
```

We can get a list of deferred expressions...

```
$vs // MapIndexed[makeAssignment[Defer]]

(* {R1[x_, y_] := x, R2[x_, y_] := y, R3[x_, y_] := inv[x], ... } *)
```

... or a list of held expressions ...

```
$vs // MapIndexed[makeAssignment[Hold]]

(* {Hold[R1[x_, y_] := x], Hold[R2[x_, y_] := y], Hold[R3[x_, y_] := inv[x]], ... } *)
```

... or a single held sequence ...

```
$vs // MapIndexed[makeAssignment[Hold]] // Apply[Hold] // Flatten

(* Hold[R1[x_, y_] := x, R2[x_, y_] := y, R3[x_, y_] := inv[x], ... ] *)
```

... as suits our fancy.

**Notes**

There are some subtleties in the definition of `makeAssignment` in order to generate the definitions we desire.

*Tailored argument list form*

We could have defined `makeAssignment` like this:

```
makeAssignment[wrapper_, e_, i_] := ...
```

instead of what we did:

```
makeAssignment[wrapper_][e_, {i_}] := ...
```

But by making `wrapper` a curried argument and using `{i_}` we made the function more convenient to use with the operator form of `MapIndexed`, i.e.:

```
... // MapIndexed[makeAssignment[Hold]]
```

vs.

```
... // MapIndexed[makeAssignment[Hold, #, #2[[1]]]&, #]&
```

Ever since version 10 dramatically increased the usage of operator forms, such syntactical niceties have become more commonplace.

*ToExpression vs. Symbol*

`makeAssignment` uses `ToExpression[..., Hold]` instead of `Symbol` to create the function names in order to ensure that we obtain an unevaluated symbol and not its value.  Consider:

```
XYZ10 = 666;

Symbol["XYZ10"]
(* 666 *)

ToExpression["XYZ10", InputForm, Hold]
(* Hold[XYZ10] *)
```

*Double Replacement*

`makeAssignment` uses two replacement expressions (`/.`) in order to construct the function definition expression.  It does this to avoid some unwelcome symbol renaming that occurs when the evaluator get defensive about the scope of the free variables `x` and `y`.  Consider:

```
Hold[V1, x + y] /. Hold[s_, e_] :> Hold[s[x_, y_] := e]
(* Hold[V1[x$_, y$_] := x + y] *)

Hold[V1, x + y] /. Hold[s_, e_] :> Hold[s[x_, y_], e] /. Hold[l_, r_] :> Hold[l := r]
(* Hold[V1[x_, y_] := x + y] *)
```

There are other strategies to deal with this, but they are all as messy as this or messier.  In fact, dealing with unevaluated expressions in *Mathematica* is generally a very messy business prone to evaluation leaks.

(I'm starting a pool on how long it takes a reader of this post to find an evaluation leak :)

*Hold vs. HoldComplete*

This post uses `Hold` liberally to prevent evaluation.  A more defensive implementation might use `HoldComplete` instead.  The differences are minor, but it is really a design choice to prefer one over the other.  For example, `HoldComplete` prevents the action of up-values.  Depending upon the wider application this might be desirable or undesirable.  In a code generation context, up-values can be very useful for implementing special rules when transforming held expressions.  On the other hand, they are a potential source of evaluation leaks and other surprising behaviours.  The designer must choose.  The use of `Hold` is far more common than that of `HoldComplete`, but this is not necessarily a conclusive argument.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you really want to do, but happy to see you seem to be using [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) :)

As for your question, why not simply:

```
rhs = {x, y, inv[x], inv[y], x ** y}
lhs = {R1, R2, R3, R4, R5}
fun = MapThread[(Hold[#1[x_, y_] := #2]) &, {lhs, rhs}]
```

When you want to create the functions in `fun`:

```
ReleaseHold /@ fun
```

If you just want to create them right away just ommit `Hold` as in:

```
fun = MapThread[(#1[x_, y_] := #2) &, {lhs, rhs}]
```